# Deferring downloads instead of being uploaded with the job?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

My goal is to update the viewer only and then offer the option to generate the items for download and I was wondering what is the best way to handle this.

Currently when we send a workitem it returns with the updated svf and updates the viewer along with creating and uploading the selected export formats(stl, stp, dwg), BOM, etc. This increases the time that the user is waiting for the workitem to return.

Is a new AppBundle required or can this be handled within the same one?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using 1 appbundle only. You just need multiple activities. Each activity can use the same appbundle, and will be defined to use different portion of appbundle which can be decided based on the command line flags. Then you can in each of the phase send workitem using needed activity.

Comment: I appreciate the response Michal. I'll give it a try and will be back with additional questions if I run into further issues.